# To compare two cells in excel and then return the row

Tags: vba, excel

Well the scenario is a excel sheet contain 97K rows with similar email address I want to compare the alternate cells in an excel sheet and get unique email address . 
Suppose their are 4 columns

1. **A contains Name**
2. **B contains Email Address**
3. **C contains type**
4. **D contains the latest updated date time**

but the conditions are :-

1. **if B contain any 2 or 3 cells having same email address then go to the next column i.e C**
2. **in column C check for the type**
3. **if all the people contain type as LEAD/CONTACT then go for the column C and check for latest update and get that row.**
4. **if the people with matching emails contain type one as LEAD and another as CONTACT then get the row which have type as CONTACT**
5. **if the type is Blank then get those row which contain any type either LEAD or CONTACT.**

So can anyone help me out , how quickly this can be done? Right now i am manually doing it one by one. A short or snippet approach is appreciable. 
Thank you.It would be a great help [image]

Comment: do you have to do this multiple times that you are asking for VBA? If no why dont you sort the data firstly for the emails and secondly by the type. There is also a function implemented in the ribbon for deleting doubled data (although I'm not sure on what criteria exactly the data gets deleted). If you'd really want to do it with VBA you'll probably have to start somewhere, why don't you start with comparing one cell to another. :)

Comment: comparing cells can be easily done with "If Cells(A1).value = Cells(b1).value Then". You can also work with Cells(Row, Col) for the coordinates of a single cell. For Row and Col you could make a For-Loop which will then lead to the cells ranges being dynamic.

Comment: yes.. their are 96K records and almost every other record is having duplicate emails.

Answer (score 3):

Sort the Data in the following order:

1. Email - Ascending
2. Updated At - Descending
3. Type - Ascending

Then in Column E write the following formula: `=IF(B1<>B2,"Keep","")`

Then filter the data by blanks in Column D, then delete the filtered rows.

Picture with sample data based on your data below.
[image]

Comment: @MiliBiswas - did you read this line in my answer -> **Then filter the data by blanks in Column D, then delete the filtered rows.**

Comment: for each cell in column D.. will i have to repeat the formule? isnt there a way to get in one click?

Comment: @MiliBiswas - just drag the formula for column D. Or double-click the lower-right-hand corner of D2 when the thin cross appears, and it will auto-fill the formula down the row.

Comment: hi @scott , thankyou for the help, but i think the sorting order is not same as what you did .. I first sort the EMAIL then Updated at and then TYPE .. all the email of alternative cell are different then, so eventually the formula gives KEEP for all.. now what to do? Is this correct way..?

Comment: @MiliBiswas did you sort them in the `Ascending` and `Descending` order as I have outlined in the answer. Also, please make sure the formula is just as I have written in the answer as well.

Comment: yes i did.. but after sorting the 3 columns .. i didn't get exactly the sheet as urs... can you please tell the sequence again..? like first second  and third?